# Rename specific columns with numbers with str+number

Tags: python, pandas

I originally have r number of csv files.

I created one dataframe with 9 columns and r of them have numbers as headers.

I would like to target only them and change their name into ['Apple']+range(len(files)).

Example:
I have 3 csv files.

The current 3 targeted columns in my dataframe are:

```
            0       1       2  
0       444.0   286.0   657.0  
1      2103.0  2317.0  2577.0  
2       157.0   200.0   161.0  
3      4000.0  3363.0  4986.0  
4      1042.0   541.0   872.0  
5      1607.0  1294.0  3305.0
```

I would like:

```
       Apple1  Apple2    Apple3  
0       444.0   286.0   657.0  
1      2103.0  2317.0  2577.0  
2       157.0   200.0   161.0  
3      4000.0  3363.0  4986.0  
4      1042.0   541.0   872.0  
5      1607.0  1294.0  3305.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can initialise a `itertools.count` object and reset the columns in a list comprehension.

```
from itertools import count

cnt = count(1)
df.columns = ['Apple{}'.format(next(cnt)) if 
       str(x).isdigit() else x for x in df.columns]
```

This will also work very well if the digits are not contiguous, but you want them to be renamed with a contiguous suffix:

```
print(df)
       1   Col1       5    Col2     500
0  1240.0  552.0  1238.0    52.0  1370.0
1   633.0  435.0   177.0  2201.0   185.0
2  1518.0  936.0   385.0   288.0   427.0
3   212.0  660.0   320.0   438.0  1403.0
4    15.0  556.0   501.0  1259.0  1298.0
5   177.0  718.0  1420.0   833.0   984.0

cnt = count(1)
df.columns = ['Apple{}'.format(next(cnt)) if 
         str(x).isdigit() else x for x in df.columns]

print(df)
   Apple1   Col1  Apple2    Col2  Apple3
0  1240.0  552.0  1238.0    52.0  1370.0
1   633.0  435.0   177.0  2201.0   185.0
2  1518.0  936.0   385.0   288.0   427.0
3   212.0  660.0   320.0   438.0  1403.0
4    15.0  556.0   501.0  1259.0  1298.0
5   177.0  718.0  1420.0   833.0   984.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rename_axis:

```
df.rename_axis(lambda x: 'Apple{}'.format(int(x)+1) if str(x).isdigit() else x, axis="columns")
Out[9]: 
   Apple1  Apple2  Apple3
0   444.0   286.0   657.0
1  2103.0  2317.0  2577.0
2   157.0   200.0   161.0
3  4000.0  3363.0  4986.0
4  1042.0   541.0   872.0
5  1607.0  1294.0  3305.0
```